# fullscreen modal close when click inside

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a button and I want to open a full-screen section that contains some inputs

I tried bootstrap's full-screen modal like this:

```css
.filter-modal {
background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <h3> without static backdrop "</h3>

<button type="button" class="w-50 " data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#filterModal"  data-keyboard="false">
    <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
    modal without static backdrop
  </button>

<div class="filter-modal modal fade modal-fullscreen" id="filterModal" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"  aria-hidden="true"  >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <div class="modal-header">
        <p class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> item 1</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio1" name="optradio" value="option1" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1">item2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio2" name="optradio" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">  item 3</label>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
    </div>
  
  <hr>
  <h3> with static backdrop "</h3>
  <button type="button" class="w-50 " data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#filterModal"  data-keyboard="false">
    <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
    modal with static backdrop
  </button>

<div class="filter-modal modal fade modal-fullscreen" id="filterModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"  aria-hidden="true"  >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <div class="modal-header">
        <p class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> item 1</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio1" name="optradio" value="option1" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1">item2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio2" name="optradio" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">  item 3</label>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

But when I clicked anywhere on the modal, it closed
to fix this I tried adding `data-backdrop=" static"` to the modal, and now it doesn't close on click but none of the buttons and inputs is working also the modal's close button because the same thing happens and it assumes I'm clicking outside, and it tries to say that a modal with an static backdrop is open
and as I said, the modal's close button doesn't work too.

**As I mentioned before in both situations it assumes I'm clicking outside the modal, but it's a full-screen modal.**

Any solution?

Comment: Why is there a dot in your classlist ` class="filter-modal modal fade .modal-fullscreen"`

Comment: @Andy just a typing mistake! edited

Comment: And it didn’t change anything? Could you try to produce an interactive code snippet that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @Andy just did, when you click on button a full screen modal will open, but when you click anywhere on the modal it will close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Bootstrap Modal Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#modal-components), I found two issues with your code:

1. The `modal-fullscreen` class should be added to the `modal-dialog` element, not the `modal` element
2. The `modal-content` was missing

The latter became obvious because you needed to apply a CSS correction for the background which shouldn’t be necessary. This is what fixes the issue.

The code had some other weird parts which I corrected

- `aria-labelledby` should be present in the `modal` element, and point to the title
- `data-keyboard` has no meaning in HTML or Bootstrap, at least I couldn’t find anything. If it was intended to deactivate keyboard control: That’s a horrible thing to do
- Popper is not necessary for modals

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button type="button" class="w-50 " data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#filterModal">
    <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
    modal without static backdrop
  </button>

<div class="modal fade" id="filterModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> item 1</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio1" name="optradio" value="option1" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio1">item2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio2" name="optradio" value="option2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">  item 3</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```